# How to open a file in java

Tags: java, file

I want to open a file. I do it step by step using tutorial but it doesn't work. It shows a window with information about compile error. I do not know where is a mistake. What should I change?

```
private void otworzActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
int odpowiedz = jFileChooserotworz.showOpenDialog(this);
      if (odpowiedz == jFileChooserotworz.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          File file = jFileChooserotworz.getSelectedFile();
          try {
              Text.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );
          } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("Nie mogę otworzyć pliku: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
              System.out.println("Problem: "+e);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: show us the error pls.

Comment: welcome to SO! if you want fast and correct answer - please share all relevant data- so please add the exception you are receiving

Comment: Please share not only your error but also the complete code.

if this is it then jFileChooserotworz is an issue..it does not exists

Comment: Most likely you are trying to use a class which you haven't imported, possibly because you don't have a class or instance you are trying to use.

Comment: Use `Files.newBufferedReader()` instead of `new FileReader()`

Comment: run:
J:\.AppData\netbeans\cache\7.3.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 
Cancelled by user.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: Files.newBufferedReader() doesn't work

Comment: What is `Text.read`? Can you show it if it's a custom class?

Comment: Text it's name of TextArea read I think it's function.

Comment: I don't add null when I should :).    Now i have this error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class File
  location: class a.NewJFrame
 at a.NewJFrame.otworzActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:108)
 at a.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:11)
 at a.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:48)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)